# Sending Double typed data directly from C to MySQL

Tags: mysql, c, double

I am using MySQL C API.
Now I have some Double Typed data in C, and I want to insert them to a database.
All I know now is to use mysql_real_query() with a statement string to do this.
I am worrying about losing precision, since the process above involves double to string then to double. Is there a way to avoid this? Like sending double binary data directly to MySQL? I assume MySQL implements double the same as C does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a [prepared statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-stmt-prepare.html) with a placeholder for your `double` and then you can bind a `double` without converting anything to a string. Something like this:

```
char *insert = "insert into pancakes (d) values (?)";
MYSQL_BIND b;
MYSQL_STMT *stmt = mysql_stmt_init(mysql);
mysql_stmt_prepare(stmt, insert, strlen(insert));

b.buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_DOUBLE;
b.buffer = &your_double;
/* Fill in the rest of b...*/
mysql_stmt_bind_param(stmt, &b);
```

References:

- [`mysql_stmt_init`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-stmt-init.html)
- [`mysql_stmt_prepare`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-stmt-prepare.html)
- [Type Codes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/c-api-prepared-statement-type-codes.html)
- [`mysql_stmt_bind_param`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-stmt-bind-param.html)